# play midi files in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, midi

is there a way to play midi files in flash? using actionscript 3?

Comment: You could try this (never used it myself, though): ( http://code.google.com/p/midas3/wiki/MidAs3 )

Comment: That's about all I could find via Google. Since there doesn't appear to be very good support for MIDI in Flash, I'd recommend converting MIDI to MP3 and using that instead.

Comment: Important note: when converting to MP3, make sure the sample rate is 44,100 hz or you will have problems.

Comment: @Michael Todd I couldn't get that sample to work. And their demo seems to be down. Where is the main file?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that project; it was just one of the few promising-looking results on a Google search for you. Sorry that it didn't pan out. It still looks like it's going to be a lot easier to just convert to MP3 to begin with (if there aren't _too_ many to convert).

Comment: There is another project on Google code: http://code.google.com/p/flash-midi-player/